Does Genesis 2:9 have a sense of experiential knowledge as compared to other types of knowledge?
From the Amplified Bible, Genesis 2:9:

And [in that garden] the LORD God caused to grow from the ground every tree that is desirable and pleasing to the sight and good (suitable, pleasant) for food; the tree of life was also in the midst of the garden, and the tree of the [experiential] knowledge (recognition) of [the difference between] good and evil.

I am wondering what differentiates "experiential" knowledge from other types of knowledge? Is the word "experiential" truly implied by the original text? I could not find any references to this in the Strong's entry for the word translated as knowledge here (h1847). Are there multiple words for knowledge used in different ways in scripture?

When questions like this arise, one can access the literal Hebrew of the Masoretic Text, the Dead Sea Scrolls where available (missing in this case), and the literal Greek Septuagint. One can also see what the translators used in other passages that use the same Hebrew or Greek words.
The Hebrew word used here for knowledge is hadda'aṯ, which is in most cases translated simply as knowledge.
See https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h1847/esv/wlc/0-1/
However, the reason I often access the Septuagint is for two reasons:

The LXX was translated into Greek over two centuries before Christ, escaping the "emendations of the scribes" and the "corrections" (their term) of the Masoretes.
The LXX represents a snapshot of how pre-Christian era Jewish scholars under the auspices of the Sanhedrin interpreted these scriptures.

The Apostolic Bible Polyglot translation of the LXX reads as follows (using English word order):

And God caused to rise up yet from out of the earth every beautiful
tree to the sight, and good for food; and the tree of life in the
midst of the paradise, and the tree to perceive good and evil. -
Genesis 2:9 ABP

Here, we see the interpretation that did not specify experiential knowledge but perception and an implied ability to make a judgment between them.

The Amplified Bible is an interpretive translation which sometimes uses the LXX for extra information.  Gen 2:9 is a perfect example of this.
At the heart of the OP's question is the Hebrew word דַּעַת (da'ath) which is simply knowledge or skill (of workmanship, BDB).  The "simple" translation of this word to Greek would have been γνῶσις (gnosis).
However, the Hebrew is more complex and rarely has simple abstract nouns like γνῶσις.  Thus, the LXX decided to translate the Hebrew word with a phrase:

τοῦ εἰδέναι γνωστὸν = of the learning/perception of knowledge

This reflects the idea that the tree of the knowledge of good and evil did not itself impart any knowledge, but only eating its fruit would provide an experience of what evil is.  That is, Adam and Eve as created in their perfect innocence had not conception of evil which could only be acquired by experience.
Ellicott addresses this point when he comments:

“the tree of knowledge of good and evil,” must have acquired this name
after the fall. As long as Adam and Eve were in their original
innocence they had no knowledge of evil, nor could any mere mental
development bestow it upon them. They must either feel it in
themselves, or see it in others, before they could know it.

The Hebrew word for "knowledge" דַּעַת (da'ath) has the concept of a skill of a skillful craftsman acquired by long experience.
All this is presumably the basis for the Amplified Bible's version:

the [experiential] knowledge (recognition)

